PDF getting cut off
I set up a PDF to get sent from google sheets but when I send it the whole right side is getting cut off. I set it as Landscape but it still doesn't capture the whole document.
I want the whole sheet to show.
Here is the code I am using:
/**
 * Creates a PDF for the customer given sheet.
 * @param {string} ssId - Id of the Google Spreadsheet
 * @param {object} sheet - Sheet to be converted as PDF
 * @param {string} pdfName - File name of the PDF being created
 * @return {file object} PDF file as a blob
 */
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName) {
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=0&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=false&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  // Gets the folder in Drive where the PDFs are stored.
  // const folder = getFolderByName(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME);
   const folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('(P) HIVE EOS');

   if (folders.hasNext()) {
    const folder = folders.next();

    const pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
    return pdfFile;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Folder could not be found');
  }
}


Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

This question needs more focus. Do you already understand the code included in the question?

@Codedabbler Since the answer on your comment is working, kindly post it as an answer so that other people in the community can also see it.

Your last column to display is set to Column 9 per this line in your code: lc = 9.
Change that to whichever should be the last column displayed in your PDF.
